# Print and execute using sed

Tags: sed

I have a list of domain names in a file. I have to get 'A Record' for each domain name.

Input:

```
:~$ cat domainlist.txt 
google.com
yahoo.com
facebook.com
```

Required Output:

```
google.com  
216.58.220.46  
yahoo.com  
98.139.183.24  
206.190.36.45  
98.138.253.109  
facebook.com  
66.220.146.36
```

So, I have this sed command which helps me to get A Records.

```
sed 's/^/dig +short A/e' domainlist.txt
```

But it just outputs the IP. The domain names are not printed with it.

Output:

```
:~$ sed 's/^/dig +short a/e' domainlist.txt 
98.124.199.55
188.125.73.108
74.6.50.150
77.238.184.150
98.137.236.150
199.59.243.120
```

I could get the required output using bash. But I want to know is there any way to get this ouput using sed as it minimizes the code lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what the `e` flag to the `s` command does (emphasis mine):

> This command allows one to pipe input from a shell command into pattern space. If a substitution was made, the command that is found in pattern space is executed **and pattern space is replaced with its output**. A trailing newline is suppressed; results are undefined if the command to be executed contains a nul character. This is a GNU sed extension.

So you remove what you'd like to print, but the fix is simple:

```
$ sed 'p;s/^/dig +short A/e' domainlist.txt 
google.com
98.124.199.55
yahoo.com
74.6.50.150
98.137.236.150
77.238.184.150
188.125.73.108
facebook.com
199.59.243.120
```

Just print the pattern space before replacing it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have `dig` on my system but this is the job `xargs` was created to do:

```
xargs -n 1 -I % sh -c 'echo %; dig +short A %;' < domainlist.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

with `awk`

```
awk '{cmd="dig "$0" +short";print $0; while((cmd|getline var) > 0){ print var};close(cmd) }' domainlist.txt
```